# p4 : A submitted change was reopened for review on the perforce review board by mistake. How do I get it back to the submitted state?

Tags: perforce

Perforce newbie here, I submitted a changelist using "p4 submit" after the review on perforce review board, it was accidentally reopened for review through the review board. Now it shows "status: Re-opened", how to I get it back to the submitted state ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the review board, but I imagine the change was `unsubmit`ted, in which case presumably you want to `submit` it.  At the command line this would be:

```
p4 submit -e CHANGE
```

to submit the shelved changelist directly, or:

```
p4 unshelve -s CHANGE
p4 submit
```

to unshelve it into your workspace first (e.g. if you need to make any edits or resolve other changes or whatever).